# React- Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-forms

I was making a registration from for creating a profile. After entering the value,when I click submit I get this error

[image]

profile.js

```
import axios from "axios";
import { setAlert } from "./alert";

import { GET_PROFILE, PROFILE_ERROR } from "./types";

export const getCurrentProfile = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get("/api/profile/me");

    dispatch({
      type: GET_PROFILE,
      payload: res.data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: PROFILE_ERROR,
      payload: {
        msg: error.response.statusText,
        status: error.response.status,
      },
    });
  }
};

//Create or Update profile
export const createProfile =
  (formData, history, edit = false) =>
  async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      const config = {
        headers: {
          "Content=Type": "application/json",
        },
      };
      const res = await axios.post("/api/profile", formData, config);

      dispatch({
        type: GET_PROFILE,
        payload: res.data,
      });

      dispatch(setAlert(edit ? "Profile Updated" : "Profile Created"));

      if (!edit) {
        history.push("/dashboard");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      const errors = error.response.data.errors;

      if (errors) {
        errors.forEach((error) => dispatch(setAlert(error.msg, "danger")));
      }

      dispatch({
        type: PROFILE_ERROR,
        payload: {
          msg: error.response.statusText,
          status: error.response.status,
        },
      });
    }
  };
```

CreateProfile.js

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from "react";
import { Link, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { createProfile } from "../../actions/profile";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const CreateProfile = ({ createProfile, history }) => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    status: "",
    company: "",
    bio: "",
    website: "",
    location: "",
    skills: "",
    github_username: "",
    twitter: "",
    facebook: "",
    linkedin: "",
  });

  const [displaySocialInputs, toggleSocialInputs] = useState(false);

  const {
    status,
    company,
    bio,
    website,
    location,
    skills,
    github_username,
    twitter,
    facebook,
    linkedin,
  } = formData;

  const onChange = (e) =>
    setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    createProfile(formData, history);
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <h1 className='large text-primary'>Create Your Profile</h1>
      <p className='lead'>
        <i className='fas fa-user'></i> Let's get some information to make your
        profile stand out
      </p>
      <small>* = required field</small>
      <form className='form' onSubmit={(e) => onSubmit(e)}>
        <div className='form-group'>
          <select name='status' value={status} onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}>
            <option value='0'>* Select Professional Status</option>
            <option value='Developer'>Developer</option>
            <option value='Junior Developer'>Junior Developer</option>
            <option value='Senior Developer'>Senior Developer</option>
            <option value='Manager'>Manager</option>
            <option value='Student or Learning'>Student or Learning</option>
            <option value='Instructor'>Instructor or Teacher</option>
            <option value='Intern'>Intern</option>
            <option value='Other'>Other</option>
          </select>
          <small className='form-text'>
            Give us an idea of where you are at in your career
          </small>
        </div>
        <div className='form-group'>
          <input
            type='text'
            placeholder='Company'
            name='company'
            value={company}
            onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
          />
          <small className='form-text'>
            Could be your own company or one you work for
          </small>
        </div>
        <div className='form-group'>
          <input
            type='text'
            placeholder='Website'
            name='website'
            value={website}
            onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
          />
          <small className='form-text'>
            Could be your own or a company website
          </small>
        </div>
        <div className='form-group'>
          <input
            type='text'
            placeholder='Location'
            name='location'
            value={location}
            onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
          />
          <small className='form-text'>
            City & state suggested (eg. Boston, MA)
          </small>
        </div>
        <div className='form-group'>
          <input
            type='text'
            placeholder='* Skills'
            name='skills'
            value={skills}
            onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
          />
          <small className='form-text'>
            Please use comma separated values (eg. HTML,CSS,JavaScript,PHP)
          </small>
        </div>
        <div className='form-group'>
          <input
            type='text'
            placeholder='Github Username'
            name='githubusername'
            value={github_username}
            onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
          />
          <small className='form-text'>
            If you want your latest repos and a Github link, include your
            username
          </small>
        </div>
        <div className='form-group'>
          <textarea
            placeholder='A short bio of yourself'
            name='bio'
            value={bio}
            onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
          ></textarea>
          <small className='form-text'>Tell us a little about yourself</small>
        </div>

        <div className='my-2'>
          <button
            onClick={() => toggleSocialInputs(!displaySocialInputs)}
            type='button'
            className='btn btn-light'
          >
            Add Social Network Links
          </button>
          <span>Optional</span>
        </div>

        {displaySocialInputs && (
          <Fragment>
            <div className='form-group social-input'>
              <i className='fab fa-twitter fa-2x'></i>
              <input
                type='text'
                placeholder='Twitter URL'
                name='twitter'
                value={twitter}
                onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
              />
            </div>

            <div className='form-group social-input'>
              <i className='fab fa-facebook fa-2x'></i>
              <input
                type='text'
                placeholder='Facebook URL'
                name='facebook'
                value={facebook}
                onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
              />
            </div>

            <div className='form-group social-input'>
              <i className='fab fa-linkedin fa-2x'></i>
              <input
                type='text'
                placeholder='Linkedin URL'
                name='linkedin'
                value={linkedin}
                onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
              />
            </div>
          </Fragment>
        )}

        <input type='submit' className='btn btn-primary my-1' />
        <a className='btn btn-light my-1' href='dashboard.html'>
          Go Back
        </a>
      </form>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

CreateProfile.propTypes = {
  createProfile: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default connect(null, { createProfile })(withRouter(CreateProfile));
```

Everything before this was working fine.I was able to log in,check if the user has a profile or not,but this error: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'data' of undefined I've checked many sources but I can't find what is wrong.

My sand box [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-microservice-qdusy?file=/server.js) for the project

Comment: Can you please share a sandbox link so we can contribute

Comment: Check that has your error object response property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem.

So the first issue I came across is that I can't enter a Github user name when creating a profile.

Which is because in my CreateProfile.js I have github_username in state, but the input name is name="githubusername" And I am updating state using the name as the key in state, so the value never changes.

So change the name to match

```
        name="github_username"
```

After that I can enter a Github user name and I tried to submit the form, but it still didn't solve the issue completely.

The error is actually coming from my config object in actions/profile.js createProfile function because I have..

```
    "Content=Type": "application/json",
```

Which should be

> Content-Type not Content=Type